# backpack-for-laravel n-n relationship and select-multiple fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have three tables, **accomodations**, **rooms** and **accommodation_rooms**.

In rooms I have id and room_name fields, together with timestamp create/modified fields and other setting fields.

The third table is the xref table, with the two **accomodation_id** and **room_id** fields.

As explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many I setup my rooms method in my accomodation model explicitly:

```php
    public function rooms()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Room', 'accomodation_rooms', 'accomodation_id', 'room_id');
    }
```

Then I try to setup a field like this:

```php
    $room = [
        [       // Select2Multiple = n-n relationship (with pivot table)
        'label' => "Rooms",
        'type' => 'select2_multiple',
        'name' => 'rooms', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'entity' => 'rooms', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'room_name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model' => "App\Models\Rooms", // foreign key model
        'pivot' => true, // on create&update, do you need to add/delete pivot table entries?
        ]
    ];

    $this->crud->addField($room);
```

But I get the following error on vendor/backpack/crud/src/PanelTraits/Fields.php, line 37:

> Undefined index: name

where I have this code:

```php
    // if the label is missing, we should set it
    if (! isset($completeFieldsArray['label'])) {
        $completeFieldsArray['label'] = mb_ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $completeFieldsArray['name']));
    }
```

Please help.

Laravel 5,7, backpackforlaravel 3.5.

Comment: why are you only checking if `$completeFieldsArray['label']` is set just after it you use `$completeFieldsArray['name']` which seems to not exist

Comment: Hi. I am not checking it. I've followed the guidelines here: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-fields#select2_multiple-n-n-relationship on how to setup a n-n multiple choice select field. The error seems to come from inside the "backpack package".

Comment: Can you `dd($completeFieldsArray)` ?

Comment: Hi. dd just inside the called file tells me:

array:1 [

  0 => array:7 [

    "label" => "Rooms"

    "type" => "select2_multiple"

    "name" => "rooms"

    "entity" => "rooms"
    "attribute" => "room_name"
    "model" => "App\Models\Rooms"
    "pivot" => true
  ]
]

And it seems me that this i a correct output.

Comment: As you can see you use `$completeFieldsArray['name']` and you should use `$completeFieldsArray[0]['name']`

Comment: I'm not using the array item directly. I am using backpack, a crud framework that is supposed to do all that kind of stuff for me. But I'm having trouble with many-to-many relationship fields.

Comment: Ok I must have missed that :) In that case have you tried `hasMany()` instead of `belongsToMany()` relationship?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I did it. It didn't work. It should not.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got my mistype error.
The field definition array should be a simpler one, without one level of square brackets.

```
$room = [ // Select2Multiple = n-n relationship (with pivot table)
    'label' => "Rooms",
    'type' => 'select2_multiple',
    'name' => 'rooms', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
    'entity' => 'rooms', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
    'attribute' => 'room_name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
    'model' => "App\Models\Rooms", // foreign key model
    'pivot' => true, // on create&update, do you need to add/delete pivot table entries?
];
```